# Missing stylable field MvxExpandableListView_GroupItemTemplate

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvmcross

I've noticed the following MvxBind info message being output to logcat while debugging on Android:

> Missing stylable field MvxExpandableListView_GroupItemTemplate

I've tried adding the MvxBindingAttributes.xml file from [GitHub](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/4.0/MvvmCross/Binding/Droid/Resources/values/MvxBindingAttributes.xml) to the DroidProject\Resources\values folder and set the Build Action to AndroidResource.  This causes a compiler error for each `<declare-stylable>` XML tag like:

> Attribute "XXX" has already been defined

It's interesting because it claims `MvxGroupItemTemplate` is already defined when I compile, yet when I run the program a message is displayed saying it's missing.

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: I've had this issue before. It came from out-of-date packages. Did you recently update your MvvmCross version to 4.0?

Comment: Yes, the project was updated to 4.0 a few days after it was out of beta.  The project started with version 3.5 -> 3.5.1 -> 4.0.  If it makes any difference, the project was started with Ninja Coder VS2013 extension then moved to VS2015.

Comment: Do you have any nuget packages other than the officially supportted ones that depend on MvvmCross? I had a problem where I had to migrate a package to MvvmCross 4.0 in order to make it work. It can be your problem too

Comment: @WilliamBarbosa I've edited the post with some new information I found.  I'm using many of the official plugins and they are all showing version 4.0 according to NuGet.  I've verified there are no leftover 3.5.x folders in my packages directory.  I also use one of Cheesebaron's plugins for settings, but it was also updated for 4.0.

Comment: I also got this problem, the message is there on every deploy, but once in a while my app crashes because of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem this morning when updating to the latest version of Xamarin Studio. Fixed it for now by including this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
  <declare-styleable name="MvxExpandableListView">
    <attr name="GroupItemTemplate" format="reference"/>
  </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

In the Resources\values\attrs.xml file.